# How to set up meetings/appointments through time slots using Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

I am creating a form response, using Google forms. The module should be posted on my (Google) website and should be used by people to set meetings with me.

I provide some options regarding the periods I am available.
Indeed I set up a question: "When do you want to meet me" and I am providing multiple answers.

My question is this. Suppose I indicate that I am free Monday and Tuesday at 10:00. Someone will decide to book the meeting with me on Monday. Is it possible to drop automatically Monday at 10:00 from the multiple answers, such that a second person will not pick up exactly the same time chosen by someone else?

If this is not possible, is there any other option that can do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of achieving the above.

### Manually

You can find a more general post about how to manually accomplish it over at Stackoverflow: [remove selected items from google form dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19270325/1527780).

### Using an add-on

Another way would be by using one of the free add-ons:

- [Choice Eliminator 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/choice-eliminator-2/mnhoinjhhhafgieggnhjekliaodnkigj) or
- [Choice Eliminator light](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/choice-eliminator-lite/bnhfpdpmedfdodojojabjlpchcjemlml)

Both by [Bjorn Behrendt](https://sites.google.com/site/edlistenscripts/gchoiceeliminator) offered at the Google web store scripted just for such needs.
Please have a look at this thorough [YouTube video list](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHDDAf9CCJg&list=PLR82RnaWE64mSdajpAL4IWHZxmk79_Pa4) on how to use them.
In your case, I believe that "Choice Eliminator light" should be sufficient.
Should you face any issues using any of the add-ons, there is a very active [Google Plus Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/109383908101699779995/stream/60ff2131-e26e-462a-8802-28ee9f6c3c8c) you can turn to.

**Keep in mind though**: One of the main caveats of what you are trying to achieve (either manually or through an add-on) is the time lapse between form submission and scripts execution. Most of the errors occurring are when submissions fall into that space in time resulting overlapping issues.